# Which Android API classes must have their methods runOnUiThread?

Tags: android, android-runonuithread

Despite Android being a multi-threaded, some API classes impose a strict requirement of having to only run on the UI thread.

For example,

1. All [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer)'s methods *"must be invoked only from the main application thread."*
2. The Android Developer's [Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads) section describes components from the [android.widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary) and [android.view](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary) packages as having to run on the main/UI thread.
3. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25277870/2597758), [TextToSpeech](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech) constructor also needs to be called from the main/UI thread.
4. The CountDownTimer must also be created on the UI thread, [if its thread does not have a Looper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25754427/2597758).

Which other classes require their methods [runOnUiThread()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))?

Is there a comprehensive list of such classes in the Android SDK?

Comment: "Is there a comprehensive list of such classes in the Android SDK?" -- no.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. Maybe this thread can start such a comprehensive list (that updates as Android SDK/API changes).

Comment: "I 'll know when I see it". Having all of them here is impossible (and pointless).